# How to show estimates of sub tasks in the scrum board?

Tags: jira, agile

I try to estimate my new sprint, and I added estimates to all sub tasks of one task. Unfortunately, there is no aggregated estimated value of the task itself in my scrum board.
How can I get this aggregated estimated value of all subtasks to my scrum board and use it in the summary estimated time of the sprint?

Comment: This question isn't suitable on StackOverflow.  You should probably post this on Project Management StackExchange: http://pm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open feature request on Atlassian for this this functionality. But it doesn't look like it will be added any time soon.

Here are the details: [Sum estimates from sub-tasks in user stories](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/GHS-9167)